# SQL Server filtering out duplications and more

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need help with SQL Server 2014 (v12.0) filtering out duplicates and this might be too big of an ask, but any help would be appreciated. After importing a table of data, we have some duplicates that we would like to manage.

Example of the data is here:

| eCRFNo | NotesURL | Assignee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | aaa.com | Person 1 |
| 101 | aaa.com | Person 2 |
| 101 | aaa.com | Person 3 |
| 101 | bbb.com | Person 4 |

The goal is to only have 1 unique Control Number (`eCRFNo`) in the table. If there are duplicates of `eCRFNo` and `NotesURL`, then the first one (ordered by `eCRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee`) should be picked as the final record and the Assignee's of the other matches be placed in a new column called Watcher (concatenated).

If there is a duplicate `eCRFNo` with a `NotesURL` that isn't a duplicate, then only the first (ordered by `eCRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee`) should be kept and "Replication" be added to a new column called Label.

The results of the example should look like the table below:

| eCRFNo | NotesURL | Assignee | Watcher | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | aaa.com | Person 1 | Person 2, Person 3 | Replication |

It is OK that we lost bbb.com in the data and that we lost Person 4.

I will post the tables if this will post at all. I am having trouble posting with tables and code. I need help with my help.

Here is the section of code that is close to what we want:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Matched.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NotesURL ORDER BY NotesURL) routing_dup,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eCRFNo ORDER BY eCRFNo) crf_dup
    FROM 
        Matched
)
UPDATE m
SET m.Watcher = a.Watcher, 
    m.Label = a.Label, 
    m.RouteDup = a.routing_dup, 
    m.CRFDup = a.crf_dup
FROM
    (SELECT 
         cte1.UserID, cte1.NotesURL, cte1.eCRFNo, cte1.UID, 
         cte1.routing_dup, cte1.crf_dup, 
         STUFF((SELECT ';' + CAST(cte2.UserID AS varchar(max))
                FROM cte AS cte2
                WHERE cte1.NotesURL = cte2.NotesURL 
                  AND routing_dup > 1
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Watcher, 
         STUFF((SELECT 'Replication'
                FROM cte AS cte2
                WHERE cte1.eCRFNo = cte2.eCRFNo 
                  AND cte1.NotesURL <> cte2.NotesURL 
                  AND cte2.CRFDup = 2 
                  AND cte1.CRFDup = 1
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') AS Label
     FROM 
         cte AS cte1) AS a
JOIN
    matched m ON m.UID = a.UID
```

Comment: Yes, please post the tables (that always helps!), and not as an image!

Comment: What do you mean by "the first one"? Ordered by _what_?

Comment: How do you determine "First" in these scenarios? Is it first when ordered by Assignee and Notes URL?

Comment: There is no implicit notion of First in SQL. In SQL everything is an un-ordered set. To get the "first" row, you need to specify the ordering that can be applied to the data. For example, if its the first it be inserted, the data needs to include a timestamp for when it was inserted.

Comment: Also, pleae read the following, regarding showing example data; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Ordered by eCRFNo, then NotesURL, then Assignee.

Comment: So Assignee _alphabetically_? It's strange that if you are talking about "first" or "last" or "final" that there isn't some column with date/time information that would indicate _when_ an assignment happened.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker So Assignee is picked earlier in the script. I really don't care which one is picked in what order if it is a problem. The Watcher column will identify the other duplicates.

Comment: What should the value of Watcher be if you cannot find duplicates? The same with Label?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 has been fully end of life since 2019. That means it has not received any updates -- **not even critical security patches!**-- for several years now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. Updating to a supported version is job #1 here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you for your concern on the EOL of Server 2014. I just want to be sure you are correct before I address our administrators. Microsoft indicates that SQL Server 2014 has an Extended End Date of July 9, 2024. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sql-server-2014 Am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: @GRIV Thank you so much for your answer! It is exactly what we were looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using *MS SQL v12.0 (SQL Server 2014)*, you'll need to use SQL Server's XML functionality (vs. using `STRING_AGG` in *SQL Server >= 2017*).

Use a `CTE` to get the `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`, then convert your rows to an `XML` string then use SQL Server's XML functionality.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ecRFNo ORDER BY ecRFNo, NotesURL ASC) as DR,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ecRFNo ORDER BY ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee ASC) as RN
FROM your_table)
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN a.Watcher IS NOT NULL THEN 'Replication' ELSE 'Unique' END AS Label
  FROM (SELECT ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee,
  stuff( (select DISTINCT ', ' + cast(t.Assignee as varchar(max))
               from CTE t
                WHERE RN > 1 AND t.ecRFNo = a.ecRFNo AND t.NotesURL = a.NotesURL
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, '') AS Watcher
        FROM CTE a WHERE DR = 1 AND RN = 1
        GROUP BY ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee) a
```

**Note:** If duplicates are not found, the column `Watcher` will display a `NULL` value and the column `Label` will display the value `Unique`.

If you want to `UPDATE` your table and `DELETE` the rows that are no longer needed, add your new columns then wrap the query above in another `CTE` with an `UDPATE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD 
Watcher VARCHAR(250),
Label VARCHAR(25);
```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ecRFNo ORDER BY ecRFNo, NotesURL ASC) as DR,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ecRFNo ORDER BY ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee ASC) as RN
FROM your_table),
CTE2 AS 
(SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN a.Watcher IS NOT NULL THEN 'Replication' ELSE 'Unique' END AS Label
  FROM (SELECT ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee,
  stuff( (select DISTINCT ', ' + cast(t.Assignee as varchar(max))
               from CTE t
                WHERE RN > 1 AND t.ecRFNo = a.ecRFNo AND t.NotesURL = a.NotesURL
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, '') AS Watcher
        FROM CTE a WHERE DR = 1 AND RN = 1
        GROUP BY ecRFNo, NotesURL, Assignee) a)
UPDATE your_table
SET your_table.Watcher = b.Watcher, your_table.Label = b.Label
FROM CTE2 b
WHERE your_table.ecRFNo = b.ecRFNo 
  AND your_table.NotesURL = b.NotesURL 
  AND your_table.Assignee = b.Assignee
```

Finally, `DELETE` the rows you no longer require by using the `Label` column; anything not touched by the `UPDATE` above will remain `NULL`.

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE Label IS NULL
```

**Result:**

```
| ecRFNO | NotesURL | Assignee | Watcher            | Label       |
|--------|----------|----------|--------------------|-------------|
| 101    | aaa.com  | Person 1 | Person 2, Person 3 | Replication |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/K_SR9o_o).**